# Overwrite only changed style properties for Android fragmentation

Tags: android, android-styles

I define the followiung style in `values/styles.xml` of my application:

```
<style name="light_textview_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/_1_BU</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/login_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_1_and_quarter_BU</item>
</style>
```

And in my `values-xlarge/styles.xml` I modify it the following way:

```
<style name="light_textview_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/_1_BU</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/login_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_1_and_quarter_BU</item>
</style>
```

Basically changing only one property - `layout_width` becomes `wrap content` for large displays.

I have many such cases of styles. This means that I duplicate a huge number of properties between styles because of fragmenting just few properties.

Is there any cleverer way to reuse the declaration from `values/styles.xml` and specify explicitly only the changed properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the parent style and derive two different styles from it.

Look at this link about: [themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is going to spare me the double code maintenanc, but I think the styling is going to become even more complicated than it is nowadays. I am looking for even easier to use approach.